# Android KeyStoreException Unknown Error

Tags: android, encryption, keystore, android-keystore, android-fingerprint-api

I am trying to decrypt encrypted text after the user is authenticated by the Android M Fingerprint API. I have been mostly trying to follow the [Android Security samples](http://developer.android.com/samples/security.html), and the examples provided in the [`KeyGenParameterSpec`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.html) documentation. I have been able to successfully encrypt the text with the public key, but when I call `cipher.doFinal` with a `Cipher` using the private key in `DECRYPT_MODE`, I get a `KeyStoreException` "Unknown error":

```
03-15 10:06:58.074 14702-14702/com.example.app E/LoginFragment: Failed to decrypt password
        javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException
            at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:486)
            at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1502)
            at com.example.app.ui.fragment.util.LoginFragment.onAuthenticationSucceeded(LoginFragment.java:251)
            at com.example.app.ui.controller.FingerprintCallback.onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintCallback.java:21)
            at android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompat$Api23FingerprintManagerCompatImpl$1.onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManagerCompat.java:301)
            at android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompatApi23$1.onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManagerCompatApi23.java:96)
            at android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager$MyHandler.sendAuthenticatedSucceeded(FingerprintManager.java:805)
            at android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager$MyHandler.handleMessage(FingerprintManager.java:757)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Unknown error
            at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:632)
            at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.doFinal(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:224)
            at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:473)
            at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1502) 
            at com.example.app.ui.fragment.util.LoginFragment.onAuthenticationSucceeded(LoginFragment.java:251) 
            at com.example.app.ui.controller.FingerprintCallback.onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintCallback.java:21) 
            at android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompat$Api23FingerprintManagerCompatImpl$1.onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManagerCompat.java:301) 
            at android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompatApi23$1.onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManagerCompatApi23.java:96) 
            at android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager$MyHandler.sendAuthenticatedSucceeded(FingerprintManager.java:805) 
            at android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager$MyHandler.handleMessage(FingerprintManager.java:757) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

The relevant current code is as follows:

```
public KeyStore getKeyStore() {
    try {
        return KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (KeyStoreException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get an instance of KeyStore", exception);
    }
}

public KeyPairGenerator getKeyPairGenerator() {
    try {
        return KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get an instance of KeyPairGenerator", exception);
    }
}

public Cipher getCipher() {
    try {
        return Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
    } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get an instance of Cipher", exception);
    }
}

private void createKeyPair() {
    try {
        mKeyPairGenerator.initialize(
                new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_ALIAS, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                        .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP)
                        .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                        .build());
        mKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    } catch(InvalidAlgorithmParameterException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to generate key pair", exception);
    }
}

private boolean initCipher(int opmode) {
    try {
        mKeyStore.load(null);

        if(opmode == Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE) {
            PublicKey key = mKeyStore.getCertificate(KEY_ALIAS).getPublicKey();

            PublicKey unrestricted = KeyFactory.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm())
                    .generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(key.getEncoded()));

            mCipher.init(opmode, unrestricted);
        } else {
            PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) mKeyStore.getKey(KEY_ALIAS, null);
            mCipher.init(opmode, key);
        }

        return true;
    } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException exception) {
        return false;
    } catch(KeyStoreException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException
            | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException
            | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to initialize Cipher", exception);
    }
}

private void encrypt(String password) {
    try {
        initCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
        byte[] bytes = mCipher.doFinal(password.getBytes());
        String encryptedPassword = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        mPreferences.getString("password").set(encryptedPassword);
    } catch(IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to encrypt password", exception);
    }
}

private String decrypt(Cipher cipher) {
    try {
        String encryptedPassword = mPreferences.getString("password").get();
        byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(encryptedPassword, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(bytes));
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to decrypt password", exception);
    }
}
```

What could possibly be causing this "unknown error"? I have ruled out the `setUserAuthenticationRequired`, but I cannot figure out what could be causing this. I also tried using the global `mCipher` instead of the `Cipher` provided by `FragmentManagerCompat.AuthenticationCallback.onAuthenticationSucceeded` (though, I think they should be one and the same) with the same result.

---

I came across this issue while looking for an answer to [another one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35992681/android-fingerprint-api-encryption-and-decryption).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Fingerprint API Encryption and Decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35992681/android-fingerprint-api-encryption-and-decryption)

Comment: @petrsyn Although both questions were ultimately answered by the same issue found on the Issue Tracker, they are inherently different questions. The first asks specifically *how to* perform encryption and decryption, and highlights the (multiple) errors I came across while trying to find a solution. Whereas this question focuses on just *one* of those errors. I think it could be detrimental to other users trying to find a solution to this specific error if we were to remove it in favor of my other question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found my answer on the [Android Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197719); from what I understand the unrestricted `PublicKey`, created to work around another [known issue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.html), becomes incompatible with the current `Cipher`. The work-around for this is to specify an `OAEPParameterSpec` when the `Cipher` is initialized:

```
OAEPParameterSpec spec = new OAEPParameterSpec(
        "SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);

mCipher.init(opmode, unrestricted, spec);
```