# android.security.KeyStoreException: Unknown error On a rare number of devices

Tags: android, cryptography, aes, rsa, android-keystore

I'm getting `android.security.KeyStoreException: Unknown error` On a rare number of devices with different Android Versions (6 - 8)

This is my key generation code:

```
final KeyPairGenerator keyGenerator = KeyPairGenerator
                        .getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, 

ANDROID_KEY_STORE);

keyGenerator.initialize(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(ALIAS,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                    .setKeySize(2048)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                    .build());

return keyGenerator.generateKeyPair();
```

This is how I load the keyPair:

```
if (keyStore.containsAlias(ALIAS))
            {
                KeyStore.Entry entry = keyStore.getEntry(ALIAS, null);
                if (entry != null)
                {
                    if (entry instanceof KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)
                    {
                        Log.i(TAG, "KeyPair found.");
                        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pke = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) entry;
                        Certificate cert = pke.getCertificate();

                        if (cert != null)
                        {
                            return new KeyPair(cert.getPublicKey(), pke.getPrivateKey());
                        }

                        Log.w(TAG, "Cert / Public Key is null");
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is my decryption code:

```
Cipher RSACipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");          

RSACipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
return new String(RSACipher.doFinal(base64.decode(textToDecrypt)), "UTF-8");
```

Here is a sample stracktrace of a failing decryption process:

```
Caused by javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException
       at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:519)
       at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1736)
       at com.examplecompany.security.EncryptionController.decryptAsymmetric(EncryptionController.java:297)
       at com.example.crypto.android2.services.CryptoClass.decryptMessage(CryptoClass.java:684)
       at com.example.crypto.android2.services.CryptoClass.handleDecryption(CryptoClass.java:619)
       at com.example.crypto.android2.services.CryptoClass.doInBackgroundInternal(CryptoClass.java:450)
       at com.example.crypto.android2.services.CryptoClass.doInBackground(CryptoClass.java:165)
       at com.example.crypto.android2.services.CryptoClass.doInBackground(CryptoClass.java:84)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Caused by android.security.KeyStoreException: Unknown error
       at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:1137)
       at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.doFinal(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:224)
       at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:506)
       at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1736)
       at com.examplecompany.security.EncryptionController.decryptAsymmetric(EncryptionController.java:297)
       at com.example.crypto.android2.services.CryptoClass.decryptMessage(CryptoClass.java:684)
       at com.example.crypto.android2.services.CryptoClass.handleDecryption(CryptoClass.java:619)
       at com.example.crypto.android2.services.CryptoClass.doInBackgroundInternal(CryptoClass.java:450)
       at com.example.crypto.android2.services.CryptoClass.doInBackground(CryptoClass.java:165)
       at com.example.crypto.android2.services.CryptoClass.doInBackground(CryptoClass.java:84)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

It works well in 99.999% of all messages to be encrypted on thousands of devices, but sometimes it fails. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Just found a solution for a similar issue on [other question here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36020975/617373)

> I found my answer on the [Android Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197719), from what I
>   understand, the unrestricted `PublicKey`, created to work around
>   another [known issue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.html), becomes incompatible with the current
>   `Cipher`. The work around for this is to specify an
>   `OAEPParameterSpec` when the `Cipher` is initialized:

You need the following as a third argument to your `Cipher` init code

```
OAEPParameterSpec spec = new OAEPParameterSpec(
        "SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);


RSACipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey, spec); // I added the same to the init in Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE too
```