# Android encryption can't decrypt data with KeyStore Generated kaypair KeyStoreException: Unknown error

Tags: android, encryption, keystore

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt data by RSA with Android. this is my code for encrypt/decrypt

```
fun encryptStringRSA(str: String, publicKey: PublicKey): String{
    val encryptedBytes: ByteArray? = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding").run {
        init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey)
        doFinal(str.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
    }

    return Base64.encodeToString(encryptedBytes, EncryptionConstants.BASE_64_OPTIONS)
}

fun decryptStringRSA(str: String, privateKey: PrivateKey): String{
    val decryptedBytes: ByteArray = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding").run {
        init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey)
        doFinal(Base64.decode(str, EncryptionConstants.BASE_64_OPTIONS))
    }

    return String(decryptedBytes)
}
```

And it works great when I use keys generated by Node JS server(this was for sync algorithms parameters), However now I need to generate keys on Android side and this is how I do that:

```
fun generateRSAKeyPair(keyAlias: String): KeyPair {
    val startDate = GregorianCalendar()
    val endDate = GregorianCalendar()
    endDate.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1)

    val keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, ANDROID_KEYSTORE)

    val parameterSpec: KeyGenParameterSpec = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keyAlias,
        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT).run {
        setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
        setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
        setKeySize(2048)
        setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
        setCertificateNotBefore(startDate.time)
        setCertificateNotAfter(endDate.time)
        setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
        setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(30)
        build()
    }

    keyPairGenerator.initialize(parameterSpec)
    val keyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair()

    val publicKey = getPublicKey(
        Base64.encodeToString(
            keyPair.public.encoded,
            EncryptionConstants.BASE_64_OPTIONS
        )
    )
    return KeyPair(publicKey, keyPair.private)
}
```

And then get from Keystore:

```
fun initKeyPair(keyAlias: String): KeyPair{
    try {
        val keyStore: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEYSTORE).apply {
            load(null)
        }

        val entry: KeyStore.Entry = keyStore.getEntry(keyAlias, null)
        val privateKey: PrivateKey? = (entry as KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry).privateKey
        val publicKey: PublicKey? = keyStore.getCertificate(keyAlias).publicKey

        return if (privateKey == null || publicKey == null) {
            KeyHolderUtils().generateRSAKeyPair(keyAlias)
        } else {
            val publicKey2 = getPublicKey(
                Base64.encodeToString(
                    publicKey.encoded,
                    EncryptionConstants.BASE_64_OPTIONS
                )
            )
            KeyPair(publicKey2, privateKey)
        }
    }catch (ex: Exception){
        return KeyHolderUtils().generateRSAKeyPair(keyAlias)
    }
}
```

Encrypt, Sign and Verify works, but when I try to decrypt always got en KeyStoreException: Unknown error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:526)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException
    at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.getMoreData(CipherInputStream.java:133)
    at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:202)
    at com.test.communication.encryption.utils.EncryptionUtils.decryptStringRSA(EncryptionUtils.kt:46)
    at com.test.communication.encryption.AndroidEncryptionBase.decryptMessage(AndroidEncryptionBase.kt:72)
    at com.test.communication.encryption.AndroidEncryption.decryptMessage(AndroidEncryption.kt:37)
    at com.test.communication.server.MessageServiceImpl.send(MessageServiceImpl.kt:97)
    at com.test.app.presentation.ui.main.CommunicationActivity$initButtons$1.onClick(CommunicationActivity.kt:64)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7201)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7170)
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:806)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27562)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7682)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
 Caused by: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:519)
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:531)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2002)
    at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.getMoreData(CipherInputStream.java:130)
    at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:202) 
    at com.test.communication.encryption.utils.EncryptionUtils.decryptStringRSA(EncryptionUtils.kt:46) 
    at com.test.communication.encryption.AndroidEncryptionBase.decryptMessage(AndroidEncryptionBase.kt:72) 
    at com.test.communication.encryption.AndroidEncryption.decryptMessage(AndroidEncryption.kt:37) 
    at com.test.communication.server.MessageServiceImpl.send(MessageServiceImpl.kt:97) 
    at com.test.app.presentation.ui.main.CommunicationActivity$initButtons$1.onClick(CommunicationActivity.kt:64) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7201) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7170) 
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:806) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27562) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7682) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
 Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Unknown error
    at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:1303)
    at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.doFinal(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:224)
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:506)
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:531) 
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2002) 
    at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.getMoreData(CipherInputStream.java:130) 
    at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:202) 
    at com.test.communication.encryption.utils.EncryptionUtils.decryptStringRSA(EncryptionUtils.kt:46) 
    at com.test.communication.encryption.AndroidEncryptionBase.decryptMessage(AndroidEncryptionBase.kt:72) 
    at com.test.communication.encryption.AndroidEncryption.decryptMessage(AndroidEncryption.kt:37) 
    at com.test.communication.server.MessageServiceImpl.send(MessageServiceImpl.kt:97) 
    at com.test.app.presentation.ui.main.CommunicationActivity$initButtons$1.onClick(CommunicationActivity.kt:64) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7201) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7170) 
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:806) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27562) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7682) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

I try different combinations of bloks(ECB, NONE) and paddings(NOPadding, PKCS1Padding, OAEPPadding, OAEPwithSHA-1andMGF1Padding and OAEPwithSHA-256andMGF1Padding) with changing `KeyGenParameterSpec` params `setEncryptionPaddings`, `setBlockModes` according combination aso I saw posts in SO like [Android KeyStoreException Unknown Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015194/android-keystoreexception-unknown-error/36020975#36020975)
and try to change code like in it, but always got same Exception.
BTW was try on different emulators and real device OnePlus 6 result the same - KeyStoreException: Unknown error

UPDATE!!!
I found some weird think if I copy all this code to Activity all works fine, but when I call it from another class then got an error. For Example:

```
fun fire(){

    val str = "test"
    val encryptionUtils = EncryptionUtils()

    generateRSAKeyPair("testKeys")

    val encryptStringRSA = encryptionUtils.encryptStringRSA(str, keyPair.public)
    val decryptStringRSA = decryptStringRSA(encryptStringRSA, keyPair.private)
    println(decryptStringRSA)
}
```

this code works fine, but

```
fun fire(){

    val str = "test"
    val encryptionUtils = EncryptionUtils()

    generateRSAKeyPair("testKeys")

    val encryptStringRSA = encryptionUtils.encryptStringRSA(str, keyPair.public)
    val decryptStringRSA = encryptionUtils.decryptStringRSA(encryptStringRSA, keyPair.private)
    println(decryptStringRSA)
}
```

this code cause en exception.
EncryptionUtils the class with 100% same code as in Activity (I mean encryptStringRSA, decryptStringRSA and other)

Comment: Please complete your code to a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). How is `getPublicKey` implemented, what are the definitions of `EncryptionConstants.BASE_64_OPTIONS` and `ANDROID_KEYSTORE`? Even if some of them can be guessed, there is a risk of working with different assumptions. In particular, post the complete calls of the methods for encryption and decryption, which finally raise the exception, _so that a repro is possible_.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say that val publicKey2 = getPublicKey(
                Base64.encodeToString(
                    publicKey.encoded,
                    EncryptionConstants.BASE_64_OPTIONS
                )
            )
without this code have the same behavior

Comment: ANDROID_KEYSTORE = "AndroidKeyStore"

Comment: and one more what I found, if I copy all this code to direct to activity, all works fine, but if I call them from another class then got error.

Answer (score 0):

I found temp solution. I just rename EncryptionUtils -> EncryptionHelper
and now it works, but after some time error came's back and each time renaming is not a solution!
Hopes someone helps with this