# UserNotAuthenticatedException during FingerprintManager.authenticate()

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

I have an encrypted password stored in the Android KeyStore.

I want to decrypt that password by authenticating the user using the fingerprint API.

As far as I understand, I have to call the `FingerprintManager.authenticate(CryptoObject cryptoObject)` method to start listening for the fingerprint result. The CryptoObject parameter is created like this:

```
public static Cipher getDecryptionCipher(Context context) throws KeyStoreException {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
        SecretKey secretKey = getKeyFromKeyStore();
        final IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = getIvParameterSpec(context);

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParameterSpec);
        return cipher;

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | IOException | UnrecoverableKeyException | CertificateException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return null;
}

Cipher cipher = FingerprintCryptoHelper.getDecryptionCipher(getContext());
FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject = new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(cipher);
fingerprintManager.authenticate(cryptoObject, ...);
```

The method `getDecryptionCipher()` works correctly until the `cipher.init()`call. On this call I get an `UserNotAuthenticatedException`, because the user is not authenticated for this secretKey. Which makes sense somehow. But isn't this a loop, impossible to fulfill:

- **To authenticate the user, I want to use his/her fingerprint**
- **To listen for his/her fingerprint, I need to init the Cipher, which in return needs an authenticated user**

What's wrong here??

**EDIT:**

I work with the emulator (Nexus 4, API 23).

Here's the code I use to create the key.

```
private SecretKey createKey() {
    try {
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
        keyGenerator.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                KEY_NAME,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
        )
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(AUTHENTICATION_DURATION_SECONDS)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                .build());
        return keyGenerator.generateKey();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create a symmetric key", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which device are you testing this on? How did you generate the key?

Comment: And you've enrolled at least one fingerprint in the emulator?

Comment: @Michael It's tested on a variety of devices, ranging from Nexus devices over some Samsung and an HTC One Mini. And yes, I also tested it on the emulator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found a method to escape the Catch 22!

You do it like this:

You `try{` `.init` yout `Cipher` as usual

1. if there's no `UserNotAuthenticatedException` (because user WAS authenticated within validity period of your key i.e. because he unlocked his device a few seconds ago) then do your encrypt/decrypt routine. The end!
2. you caught `UserNotAuthenticatedException` - run `FingerprintManager.authenticate` workflow with `null` (yes!) `CryptoObject`, then in `onAuthenticationSucceeded` callback init your cipher again (yes!), but this time it won't throw `UserNotAuthenticatedException` and use this initialized instance to encrypt/decrypt (the callback returns `null` as we called it with `null` CryptoObject, so we can't use this). The end!

As simple as that...

But it took me two days to find this method by trail and error. Not to mention - it seems all authentication examples present online are wrong!

Comment: can someone confirm this, then I will mark it as correct answer

Comment: It works, just tried and escaped chicked-egg problem! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the problem was related to a known issue with the `KeyGenParameterSpec` which prevents the use of the public key without authentication (which is exactly what the public key does NOT need).

A related question/answer can be found here: [Android Fingerprint API Encryption and Decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35992681/android-fingerprint-api-encryption-and-decryption)

The workaround is to create a `PublicKey`from the originally created key and use this unrestricted PublicKey to init the cipher.
So my final cipher uses AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding and is initialized by this method:

```
public boolean initCipher(int opMode) {
    try {
        Key key = mKeyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME, null);

        if (opMode == Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE) {
            final byte[] encoded = key.getEncoded();
            final String algorithm = key.getAlgorithm();
            final X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encoded);
            PublicKey unrestricted = KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm).generatePublic(keySpec);

            mCipher.init(opMode, unrestricted);

        } else {
            final IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = getIvParameterSpec();
            mCipher.init(opMode, key, ivParameterSpec);

        }

        return true;

    } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException exception) {
        return false;

    } catch ( NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException
            | InvalidKeySpecException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | UnrecoverableKeyException | KeyStoreException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to initialize Cipher or Key: ", exception);
    }
}

@NonNull
public IvParameterSpec getIvParameterSpec() {
    // the IV is stored in the Preferences after encoding.
    String base64EncryptionIv = PreferenceHelper.getEncryptionIv(mContext);
    byte[] encryptionIv = Base64.decode(base64EncryptionIv, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return new IvParameterSpec(encryptionIv);
}
```

Comment: is this realy working? You use AES and this is a symmetric algorithm without a public key. How is it possible to generate a public key from an AES key?

Comment: it definitely works, but I can't really explain why. I had the same thoughts as you mentioned, but it's the only way I got it to word "as intended". Please feel free to improve this approach!

Comment: I don't see how this possibly could work with an AES key. First of all, there's a good chance that `getEncoded` will return `null` for a `SecretKey`/`PrivateKey`, to avoid having such key material being exposed outside the TEE. Even if that isn't the case here, `KeyFactory.getInstance` should fail for AES since it only supports DH, DSA, EC, RSA, and X.509. Seems to me like you're actually using some other key here.

Comment: It does return null, indeed