# How to get key from keystore on successful fingerprint auth

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

I'm creating an app where the user has two options to unlock their app, one is using a pin and the other is using a fingerprint. In order to use the fingerprint they must first set up a pin because this pin is the decryption key to get their encrypted details out of `SharedPreferences`.

So i've followed this tutorial here: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Fingerprint_Authentication_Tutorial#Accessing_the_Android_Keystore_and_KeyGenerator

I've managed to get the app to read a fingerprint and say whether it is valid or not. But when the fingerprint is authorised I have no idea how to get that pin out of the Android keystore.

Here is some code to demonstrate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);

    if (!keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Lock screen security not enabled in Settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Fingerprint authentication permission not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return;
    }

    if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {

        // This happens when no fingerprints are registered.
        Toast.makeText(this, "Register at least one fingerprint in Settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    generateKey();

    if (cipherInit()) {
        cryptoObject = new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(cipher);
        FingerprintHandler helper = new FingerprintHandler(this);

        helper.startAuth(fingerprintManager, cryptoObject);
    }

}

protected void generateKey() {
    try {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
            NoSuchProviderException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get KeyGenerator instance", e);
    }

    try {
        keyStore.load(null);
        keyGenerator.init(new
                KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT |
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(
                        KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                .build());
        keyGenerator.generateKey();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
            | CertificateException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public boolean cipherInit() {
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/"
                        + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
                        + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
            NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get Cipher", e);
    }

    try {
        keyStore.load(null);
        SecretKey key = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME,
                null);

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return true;
    } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException
            | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException
            | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
    }
}
```

KEY_NAME is the key(pin) i'm trying to store (I think).

Then in the `FingerprintHandler` class there is this method:

```
public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(
        FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {

    Toast.makeText(appContext,
            "Authentication succeeded.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

But how do i get the key i want out of the `result` if at all?

Comment: Where is the code that actually stores the user's pin?

Comment: I assumed the KEY_NAME variable was the pin to be stored?

Comment: No, `KEY_NAME` is the alias of the `KeyPair` generated by the `KeyPairGenerator`. It is basically a constant `String` used to retrieve a specific `KeyPair` from the `KeyStore`.

Comment: Are you planning to store the user's pin on a server, or on the device?

Comment: on the device @Bryan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So to do this I ended up encrypting the users pin in to shared preferences and then decrypting when the fingerprint auth was successful:

So to save the pin:

```
private static final String CHARSET_NAME = "UTF-8";
private static final String ANDROID_KEY_STORE = "AndroidKeyStore";
private static final String TRANSFORMATION = KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/" + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
        + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7;

private static final int AUTHENTICATION_DURATION_SECONDS = 30;

private KeyguardManager keyguardManager;
private static final int SAVE_CREDENTIALS_REQUEST_CODE = 1;


public void saveUserPin(String pin) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
    // encrypt the password
    try {
        SecretKey secretKey = createKey();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] encryptionIv = cipher.getIV();
        byte[] passwordBytes = pin.getBytes(CHARSET_NAME);
        byte[] encryptedPasswordBytes = cipher.doFinal(passwordBytes);
        String encryptedPassword = Base64.encodeToString(encryptedPasswordBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

        // store the login data in the shared preferences
        // only the password is encrypted, IV used for the encryption is stored
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = BaseActivity.prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("password", encryptedPassword);
        editor.putString("encryptionIv", Base64.encodeToString(encryptionIv, Base64.DEFAULT));
        editor.apply();
    } catch (UserNotAuthenticatedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        showAuthenticationScreen(SAVE_CREDENTIALS_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

private SecretKey createKey() {
    try {
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
        keyGenerator.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(Constants.KEY_NAME,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(AUTHENTICATION_DURATION_SECONDS)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                .build());
        return keyGenerator.generateKey();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create a symmetric key", e);
    }
}
```

Then to decrypt:

```
public String getUserPin() throws KeyStoreException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, NoSuchPaddingException, UnrecoverableKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
    // load login data from shared preferences (
    // only the password is encrypted, IV used for the encryption is loaded from shared preferences
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = BaseActivity.prefs;
    String base64EncryptedPassword = sharedPreferences.getString("password", null);
    String base64EncryptionIv = sharedPreferences.getString("encryptionIv", null);
    byte[] encryptionIv = Base64.decode(base64EncryptionIv, Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] encryptedPassword = Base64.decode(base64EncryptedPassword, Base64.DEFAULT);

    // decrypt the password
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
    keyStore.load(null);
    SecretKey secretKey = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(Constants.KEY_NAME, null);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(encryptionIv));
    byte[] passwordBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedPassword);

    String string = new String(passwordBytes, CHARSET_NAME);

    return string;
}
```

The showAuthenticationScreen method that is called looks like this:

```
private void showAuthenticationScreen(int requestCode) {
    Intent intent = keyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(null, null);
    if (intent != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }
}
```

And then to get the result back from `showAuthenticationScreen` just override `onActivityResult` and call `saveUserPin` or `getUserPin` again whichever is required.

Comment: Can you please explain why you used encryptionIV.

Comment: encryptionIV is needed to decrypt.Here it is being used while decrypting the same string again :  ```cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(encryptionIv));```

Comment: Base64.encodeToString this is encoding not encryption is it safe?

Comment: @Girish He is using Base64 to encode the encrypted bytes and save them as a string in preferences

Answer (score -2):

The way in which the tutorial you mentioned, as well as the [Fingerprint Dialog Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog) provided by Google, handles authentication is by assuming that the user is authentic when `onAuthenticationSucceeded()` is called. The Google sample takes this a step further by checking if the `Cipher` provided by the can encrypt *arbitrary* data:

```
/**
 * Proceed the purchase operation
 *
 * @param withFingerprint {@code true} if the purchase was made by using a fingerprint
 * @param cryptoObject the Crypto object
 */
public void onPurchased(boolean withFingerprint,
        @Nullable FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject) {
    if (withFingerprint) {
        // If the user has authenticated with fingerprint, verify that using cryptography and
        // then show the confirmation message.
        assert cryptoObject != null;
        tryEncrypt(cryptoObject.getCipher());
    } else {
        // Authentication happened with backup password. Just show the confirmation message.
        showConfirmation(null);
    }
}

/**
 * Tries to encrypt some data with the generated key in {@link #createKey} which is
 * only works if the user has just authenticated via fingerprint.
 */
private void tryEncrypt(Cipher cipher) {
    try {
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(SECRET_MESSAGE.getBytes());
        showConfirmation(encrypted);
    } catch (BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to encrypt the data with the generated key. "
                + "Retry the purchase", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to encrypt the data with the generated key." + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This is a valid form of authentication, but if you need to actually store and retrieve a secret (in your case a pin), it is not sufficient. Instead, you can use asymmetric cryptography to encrypt your secret, then decrypt it upon `onAuthenticationSucceeded()`. This is similar to how authentication is handled in the [`Asymmetric Fingerprint Dialog Sample`](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AsymmetricFingerprintDialog), although without a back end server.